# Jquery - 100% width slideshow whilst keeping the height propotional

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

How would I go about creating a full width slideshow which keeps its height proportional to the width?

So I have my css to create my full width image keeping its proportion:

```
#featured-slideshow {
    width: 100%;
}
#featured-slideshow .slideshow {
    width: 100%;
}
#featured-slideshow .slideshow img {
    width: 100% !important;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 892px;
}
```

And the mark up is:

```
<div id="featured-slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="images/slideshow/image-1.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slideshow/image-2.jpg" />
        <img src="images/slideshow/image-3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is as soon as I apply a jquery plugin to this such as jquery cycle, it cant rework out the width and height once you start scaling the window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm open to using other slideshow plugins or solutions.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most jquery slideshows should be compatible with the media attribute for referencing different stylesheets for different sizes of screen.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1431px) and (max-width: 1799px)" href="css/stylefifteen.css">
```

Therefore, set different sizes of slideshow for 13, 15, 21, and 27 size screens, and in each stylesheet make sure the slideshow frame as well as the img class resizes accordingly.

A demo can be seen here (non-working website - reference purely for this example) - drag the screen to different sizes and the slideshow should resize accordingly happily from a 13" all the way to a 27" screen.

[Scaling slideshow example](http://gregorwilson.com/example/v1/index.html)

I have found this much better than trying to get an 'on the fly' solution that rescales it like supersized (supersized IS great for background images though)

Comment: The slideshow in that link doesn't scale for me. But the girl is nice.

Comment: what browser are you using? - also, the minimum size set on that is 13" screen, so any smaller you will not see scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [jquery-supersized](http://buildinternet.com/live/supersized/) is more suited for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This was my initial thought - but this issue I came across was trying to have content beneath the slide show, where the height of the image is going to be dependant on the width of your browser, the content never sits right.